# How to setup Wordpress High Availability

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, high-availability, mysql-cluster

I have installed Galera Cluster on 3 cluster + 1 management.

I wanted to make it like this,

1. Server1: Home (www.domain.com)
2. Server2: For BBpress/Forum (Forum Tab Menu will forward to forum.domain.com)
3. Server3: BuddyPress Activity (Social Tab Menu will forward to social.domain.com)

The purpose I am doing this is to distribute my resource and load balancing each other at same time.

However, I have difficulty to setup Apache Load-Balancing/mod_proxy/clustering or any suitable to have high availability WordPress.

Any best suggestion/solution to make high availability WordPress? Or how to?

And another question is I tried to copy whole WordPress files & folders to Server2 connecting to local database (same data inside since it is already on Galera Cluster) but the page blank. Any advice?

OS: Centos 6.2

Thanks in advanced.